# Get sum of same column with different conditiong

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization

I'm trying to make my queries less heavy and try to also minimize the amount of queries I do by optimizing my queries, so therefor I want to put two queries in one.

```
SELECT SUM(iAmount) as `shares`,
       (SELECT SUM(iAmount)
          FROM `investments`
         WHERE `iUser = 1
           AND DATE(`iTime`) = CURDATE()) as `shares_today`
  FROM `investments` WHERE `iUser` = 1
```

This doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a backtick after `iUser`.

But in any case, there's no need for a subquery here:

```
SELECT SUM(`iAmount`) as `shares`,
       SUM(IF(DATE(`iTime`) = CURDATE(), `iAmount`, 0)) as `shares_today`
  FROM `investments`
 WHERE `iUser` = 1;
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Didn't know I could use if statements in MySQL, will come in handy in the future.